# linking JSON file to html/js

Tags: json, ajax

I made a json file, now I want to request some info from it using JS.
when I try to request through AJAX I get an error. it says "blocked by CORS policy" in the console. There's definitely a problem with linking JSON and JS/HTML

```
`let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(xhttp.responseText)
}
 };

 xhttp.open("GET", "ali.json", true);
 xhttp.send();`
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your server does not allow the `GET` request method on the JSON resource. Browsers only allow the static resources like JS and CSS to be loaded from the same domain by default.

Since in your case it is an AJAX request, you might need these configurations on your server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET -> This allows GET on AJAX requests
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Method